# Braintree not allow adding of a 2nd test card against the same account when failOnDuplicatePaymentMethod is passed in token generation

Tags: angular, braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data, braintree-vault

I'm using braintree to test card validations and not allow any duplicate card entries and everything works fine so far when i use ***FailOnDuplicatePaymentMethod!***

The issue I am facing is:

let suppose you have 2 test cards,

**A.** VISA card

**B.** Master Card *(or any other of that matter)*

And when I enter VISA Card Details in braintree vault against user A,

The vault accepts it (which is right as required),

But when i try to add a MasterCard (or any other test card) against user A,

The System **rejects** it saying **'A duplicate card can not be entered'**

I am not sure to why I'm not able to **add 2 different test cards having totally different details** in the sandbox!

~Thanks in advance.

It allows adding the same test card against two different accounts but why I'm not able to **add 2 different test cards having totally different details** in the sandbox against the same account!